# what is the correct way to save a boolean value to a text db field using the doctrine

Tags: postgresql, text, doctrine, boolean

My environment:

- "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "2.5.6"
- PG_VERSION=12.5-1.pgdg100+1
- PHP8, Symfony

While saving boolean value to text field into db I get an empty string if value is `false` and '1' if value is `true`.

I want to have 't' if value is `true` and 'f' if value is false. How to achieve this?

My code:

```
$conn->executeQuery(
 'INSERT INTO example_table (example_true, example_false) VALUES(:example_true, :example_false)',
 [
    "example_true" => true,
    "example_false" => false
 ]);
```

Comment: Why don't you use a BOOLEAN datatype for a boolean value? You wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: Actually, the value can be mixed, any scalar vale. Boolean just a case. These db fields are kinda log.